# Sitewide 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect

I am looking to perform a sitewide 301 redirect. The original site is over 15 years old! I understand the concept of making the .htaccess file with the code:

```
redirect 301 "/old/old.htm" http://www.you.com/new.html
```

However will this redirect every page of the old site? or just an individual page. How do I achieve redirection with the entire site?

Answer (score 3):

I have a rewrite in `.htaccess` (apache rewrite mod enabled), all pages from old site 
http://www.old.com and 
http://www.old.com/site/index.php? .... redirect to the new site 
http://www.new.com   or 
http://www.new.com/website/index.php?... (notice that /site/ and /website/ are different names)

pages from the old site 
https://www.old.com (notice the s on https://) get redirected fine but pages from 
https://www.old.com/site/index.php?...   do not, they get a 404 error

since the old site is not secure anymore neither the 
https://www.old.com or 
https://www.old.com/site/index.php?... really exist anymore but 
https://www.old.com gets redirected and the ones with 
/site/index.php?... added do not get redirected but go instead to a 404 error

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with a 301, 301 redirect is used for where content has moved.

e.g. content about making a cake was here /makeacake.html now is /cakes/making-a-cake.html.

what I would recommend is find the pages where the majority of your uses come to, and redirect those pages to the new relevant pages / sections and just delete the rest and add a custom 404 error page. which tells them the old content has been moved.

You can also use goggle web masters to remove pages from there index.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the old pages don't exist any more (would throw 404-errors), you can do the following: You redirect all the pages that don't exist anymore to the start page. (As specified in the comments below.)

This is the updated .htaccess code you can use to make that happen. The first RewriteCond checks if the requested path is a file, the second checks if its a directory. After that, you get redirected to the startpage - or any other page for that matter.

`http://www.example.com/i/am/an/old/page.html` or `http://www.example.com/i/am/a/different/old/page.html` will all redirect to `http://www.example.com/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, this takes care of all pages on the old host. It only works of course, if the pages have the same name.
http://{old-host}/{page} changes to http://{new-host}/{page} - whatever {page} is.

Comment: I am not changing hosts just extensions for example: www.etterengineering.com/boosters.htm becomes www.etterengineering.com/gas_boosters.html

Comment: Is there a pattern that can be adhered? (e.g. all pages {page} are redirected to gas_{page}; or all old pages get redirected to the *same* new page)
If not, you'll have to create a list of rules.

Comment: all pages can be redirected to the new index page.

Comment: Thank you for the help, apparently I was on a windows server. I fixed it with a php 301.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to redirect the entire site is by doing domain forwarding through your web server (or web host... most have the option in their control panel).

Domain forwarding is much more efficient than sending 301 redirects back to the client.

Comment: Part of the URL has changed and we do not want to lose our SEO Ranking. Is this still possible with domain forwarding?

Comment: Good question, Stephanie.  I can't say for sure how Google, Yahoo and Bing would treat a domain forward vs. a 301 redirect, but I would assume that it would be identical.  That's a great question for SearchEngineWatch.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in thinking that your site is on the same domain name but you've changed it structurally?
 
So, you have a load of old page URLs that have now changed to new URLs (but on the same domain).

For example, you may have had:
www.yourdomain.com/about-us/history.htm
that has now become
www.yourdomain.com/our-history.htm

 
If that is the case you will more than likely need to set up many 301 redirect rules. It doesn't necessarily mean that you have to set up one rule for every single page change as you can use RegEx to catch pattern changes in the URL structure. As a scale example, I recently set up a htaccess file of 301 redirects for a site with just under 600 changed URLs. There were 70-something 301 Redirect rules in the end.
 

It's not necessarily a small job but it is doable. Worth it to retain your SEO rankings.